# Combine columns in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have created this matrix with still some NA in it.

```
Att_table_S01_E031_Mod
       ID     AREA     LU_1990 LU_2000 LU_2005 CHLU_90_00 CHLU_00_05         
[1,] " 597" " 274408.8" "11"    "15"    "15"    NA         NA         
[2,] " 622" " 249063.6" "11"    "15"    "15"    NA         NA         
[3,] " 816" "  90260.9" "11"    "15"    "15"    NA         NA
```

I want the NA values to be replaced by a combination of two columns from the same matrix. For instance, I want the column CHLU_90_00 to be equal to the combination of LU_1990/LU_2000. Therefore, the column CHLU_90_00 would have the value of 1115 in these three first row. The same with the column CHLU_00_05 which will get the value of 1515 (LU_2000/LU_2005)

This work too:

```
Att_table_S01_E031_Mod [,6]<- paste0(Att_table_S01_E031_Mod [,3], Att_table_S01_E031_Mod [,4])
```

Comment: This isn't a blog here. If you have both a question and an answer, there is no reason to post it here unless you are seeking for a better answer, which isn't a case (judging by the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
mydf<-as.data.frame(Att_table_S01_E031_Mod)
mydf$CHLU_90_00<-paste0(mydf$LU_1990,mydf$LU_2000)
mat<-as.matrix(mydf)
```